# Multiple functions running at the same time

Tags: jquery

I want to show text, at the same time when the div is animating from right to left.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").animate({
                left:'5%',
    }, {duration:8000} );
    if($('.left').css('left') == '75%') {
        alert( "welcome" );
    }
  });
</script>
```

This isn't working :(

Comment: `Alert` stops execution of anything in script.

Comment: Do you want to show alert in the middle of the animation when element reaches 75%?

Comment: Not necessarily an alert, but I want to start another animation. The alert was only to test if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Alert stops the execution of code, instead of alert, try a div with text with absolute or static. And then show or hide it.

In your code, animate function will go running in a thread (javascript doesn't have threading concept but internally it works with thread) and then if block will execute only once.

If you want to show something in middle of animation, there is a progress method which will used to show progress. You can use it. It is available in jQuery 1.8+

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").animate({
                left:'5%',
    }, {
         duration:8000,
         progress: function(a, p, c ) {
             if(p==0.75)          
                console.log('welcome')
         }
    } );

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since using `alert` will pause script execution I would try using `console.log` (you can view this in the console window in chrome inside the developer tools.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").animate({
                left:'5%',
    }, {duration:8000} );
    if($('.left').css('left') == '75%') {
        //alert( "welcome" );
        console.log("welcome");

    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the code.

It had to be:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").animate({
    left:'5%',
    }, {duration:8000} );
 if($('#test').css('left') == '75%') {
        //alert( "welcome" );
        console.log("welcome");

    }
  });
</script>

But it still don't work